# Guessing a number, true or false? Python

Tags: python, numbers, boolean

I want to assign something a value and then try and get someone to guess that value. I have tried something along the lines of this but I can't seem to get it to work...:

```
   foo = 1
   guessfoo = input('Guess my number: ')
   if foo == guessfoo:
       print('Well done, You guessed it!')
   if foo != guessfoo:
       print('haha, fail.')
```

Why doesn't this work? And how should I be doing it? I am a beginner at this, please help!

Comment: Define "doesn't work", that alone is **zero** information. Also, Python 2.x or 2.x?

Comment: @delnan - print is used as a function, so it's 3.x.

Comment: in all cases, you should rather use `else` in that case.

Comment: @derekerdmann: D'oh! Yes, of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With python **version 3** :

input() returns a 'str' (string) object. A string compares to an integer returns False :

```
1 == '1'
False
```

You must cast your input like that :

```
guessfoo = int(input('Guess my number: '))
```

Don't forget to try...except if the result of the input cannot be casted into an int.

Full example code :

```
try:
    foo = 1
    guessfoo = int(input('Guess my number: '))
    if foo == guessfoo:
        print('Well done, You guessed it!')
    else:
        print('haha, fail.')
except ValueError:
    # cannot cast your input
    pass
```

---

EDIT:

With python **version 2** :

Thanks for this comment :

> In previous versions, input would eval the string, so if the user typed in 1, input returned an int.

Ouput or your original code:

```
$ python2 test.py 
Guess my number: 1
Well done, You guessed it!
```

Comment: That's only true in Python 3 - that's why I asked about the version.

Comment: what is only true for python 2?

Comment: @RestRisiko: In Python **3** (typo, edited in the meanwhile), `input` always returns a string (which makes this answer correct). In previous versions, `input` would `eval` the string, so if the user typed in `1`, `input` returned an int.

Comment: I have done as you said but it always just comes up with 'Haha, fail' Whatever number I put in. Is there something wrong in the line: if foo = guessfoo: ??

Comment: @pythonnoobface: Edit the question to include example input/output. And post your Python version.

Comment: @pythonnoobface I have edited my answer for you. Be careful with Python version 2 or 3 !

Answer (score 0):

Currently you have no condition to stop the loop. You're just printing stuff. Put a `break` after you guessed the number, or set `loop` to a different value than 1.

Answer (score 0):

Because integers (foo) aren't strings (result of input()).
If you think that Python behaves like PHP or Perl then you are wrong

1 is something completely different than '1'.

You have to either convert the string using int(..) to an int or check against 'foo'
as a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

try:
    inp = raw_input   # Python 2.x
except NameError:
    inp = input       # Python 3.x

foo = random.randint(1,10)
while True:
    guess = int(inp('Guess my number: '))
    if guess < foo:
        print('Too low!')
    elif guess > foo:
        print('Too high!')
    else:
        print('You got it!')
        break
```

Comment: "How can I repair my broken screwdriver?" - "Here, have this drill."

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the first problem will be an infinite loop, since the condition you're checking each iteration will always be true with the above code.  When you loop, you need to make sure you change something that will bring loop closer to that condition. As a start, your code should look like this:

```
loop = 1
while loop == 1:
   foo = 1
   guessfoo = input('Guess my number: ')
   if foo == guessfoo:
       print('Well done, You guessed it!')
       loop = 0
   if foo != guessfoo:
       print('Oh no, try again')
```

This will cause the loop to finish executing if the number is actually guessed.

The next problem is that `input` returns a String, so the check to see if the entered number is equal to the expected number will always fail.  In python, use the `int()` function to convert a string to a number, so that line looks like:

```
guessfoo = int(input('Guess my number: '))
```

---

At this point, you should have a decently-working loop.  However, there are a few things you could do to make your code simpler.  Here are some suggestions,  starting with the simplest tweaks and moving to cleaner code.

The first step could be to use `if...else` to make sure only one condition is executed, and you only have to check the value of `foo` once.  If the condition is true, the first branch is executed; if it fails, execution proceeds to the `else` block.

```
loop = 1
while loop == 1:
   foo = 1
   guessfoo = int(input('Guess my number: '))
   if foo == guessfoo:
       print('Well done, You guessed it!')
       loop = 0
   else:
       print('Oh no, try again')
```

This works, but we can also move the check for a correct result in the condition of the loop.  This way, the program only loops until the number is displayed:

```
foo = 1
guessfoo = 0

while foo != guessfoo:
    guessfoo = int( input( 'Guess my number: ' )

    if guessfoo != foo:
        print( 'Oh no, try again' )

print( 'Well done, You guessed it!' )
```

Now the success message will only be displayed when `foo == guessfoo`.  This loop is a bit clearer and simpler.

As a beginner, you've chosen a great place to ask for help!  Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0):

Also, should you be using two different if's?
shouldn't it be something more like

```
if foo == guessfoo:
   print('Well done, you guessed it!')
else:
   print('haha, fail.')
```