# Problems with python math

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

I'm creating program which will teach my little brother math. But for example, when program is saying 2 + 2, and I enter 4 it's saying "Incorrect!". What am I doing wrong?

```
import random
import math

def addition():
    num1 = random.randint(1, 100)
    num2 = random.randint(1, 100)
    result = num1 + num2
    guess = input(str(num1) + " + " + str(num2) + " = ")#this is the line with problem
    if guess == result:
        print("Correct!")
    if guess != result:
        print("Incorrect!")
addition()
```

Comment: You forgot to convert `guess` to an `int`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Guessing a number, true or false? Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524990/guessing-a-number-true-or-false-python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`result` is an integer (e.g., 4), and the inputed guess is a string (e.g., '4'). You need to convert them to the same type in order to compare them. E.g.:

```
result = str(num1 + num2)
```

Comment: Thanks! You helped me out!

Comment: Now, I have another problem... How can I make program make random number in loop while program isn't closed?

Comment: @RičardsLūciņš: If you really want to ask that question you should make it a separate question, with a full explanation. Don't piggy-back on your question here.

Comment: *asking questions

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the answer to int

```
 guess = int(input(str(num1) + " + " + str(num2) + " = "))
```

Answer (score 1):

typecast the `input` to `int`:

```
import random
import math
def addition():
    num1 = random.randint(1, 5)
    num2 = random.randint(1, 5)
    result = num1 + num2
    guess = input(str(num1) + " + " + str(num2) + " = ")
    guess = int(guess) #input is string and it must be typecast to int
    if guess == result:
        print("Correct!")
    if guess != result:
        print("Incorrect!")
addition()
```